# How to create a multi-dimensional Lua table with Lua C Api...?

Tags: c, lua, lua-api, lua-5.1

Hi I want lua C api to create Lua table like

```
table={['key1']={5,4,3,2},['key2']={1,0,1,1,0},['key3']={0,10,0,30,0,50}}
```

thanks in-advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [lua2c](https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/#lua2c) gives this:

```
lua_newtable(L);
lua_pushliteral(L,"key1");
lua_newtable(L);
lua_pushnumber(L,5);
lua_pushnumber(L,4);
lua_pushnumber(L,3);
lua_pushnumber(L,2);
lua_rawseti(L,-5,4);
lua_rawseti(L,-4,3);
lua_rawseti(L,-3,2);
lua_rawseti(L,-2,1);
lua_pushliteral(L,"key2");
lua_newtable(L);
lua_pushnumber(L,1);
lua_pushnumber(L,0);
lua_pushnumber(L,1);
lua_pushnumber(L,1);
lua_pushnumber(L,0);
lua_rawseti(L,-6,5);
lua_rawseti(L,-5,4);
lua_rawseti(L,-4,3);
lua_rawseti(L,-3,2);
lua_rawseti(L,-2,1);
lua_pushliteral(L,"key3");
lua_newtable(L);
lua_pushnumber(L,0);
lua_pushnumber(L,10);
lua_pushnumber(L,0);
lua_pushnumber(L,30);
lua_pushnumber(L,0);
lua_pushnumber(L,50);
lua_rawseti(L,-7,6);
lua_rawseti(L,-6,5);
lua_rawseti(L,-5,4);
lua_rawseti(L,-4,3);
lua_rawseti(L,-3,2);
lua_rawseti(L,-2,1);
lua_settable(L,-7);
lua_settable(L,-5);
lua_settable(L,-3);
lua_setglobal(L,"table");
```

This automatically generated code postpones setting table entries to the end; it can be more readable to set them as soon as possible, but you need to adjust the indices carefully.

Comment: For a recent thread on this, see http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2022-01/msg00156.html